# why libinput depends on lib wacom and does not work without them?

Tags: libinput

in ubuntu if i remove libwacom then libinput don't work, keyboard mouse won't work after logout.

In Arch linux libinput doesn't require libwacom.

Comment: You've provided no details as to what release you're talking about. Package rules are release specific (*though can be similar & often are the same*) but just software stack ages may be the answer to your *unclear* question; as you're devoid of actual specifics allowing an actual answer.

Comment: ubuntu 22.04 Lts and Kubuntu 220.04 Lts, i wanted to remove libwacom and its related packages, then i checked packages info file and libwacom libcwacom-bin libwacom-common were in dependency list of libinput package, as i know in Arch linux libinput does not need libwacom* to work, but in ubuntu look like it was set on purpose so that user don't remove it

Comment: Why would you want to remove libwacom? I am VTC as opinion-based because maintainers are responsible for dependencies.

Comment: @Pilot6 libwacom is needed for wacom tablet stuff for normal pc it is not needed and user can remove them in arch linux, but in ubuntu they configured it to be dependency so user don't remove

Comment: They don't require much space, so why spend so much effort to remove?